# Nestjs run on lambda function without creating an actual server to combine with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, model-view-controller, nestjs

I have 5 HTTP microservices written with [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/). I have to convert them into [lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) where each service will have its own lambda function. The purpose of this is to completely turn my service to serverless.

I am using [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) to map requests to the right lambda by the given request path.

Now creating an MVC pattern from scratch that receives an URL path and resolves and controller & function needed (including url params, and such) is something that has already been done by both express and nestjs.

Is there a way to implement nesstjs's abstraction functionality without the actual server listening? So I can simply pass nestjs the URI and request data and it will work upon it?

Any other solutions for running an MVC serverless process on lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching the network and looking at these great answers, I thought of collecting that information all together and bring something more detailed, things that I was misunderstanding from these articles described and the ones I found.

## How to create a serverless NestJS application using Lambda function AWS provider

Let's take a look at this repository article: https://github.com/rdlabo/serverless-nestjs

Thanks to him, he basically packed a ready-to-go NestJS project configured with the [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com).

I am not experienced enough to say a lot about the serverless framework, but I can explain how it works in our case.

First of all, there is a `serverless.yml` as explained the the github repository article, basically here you describe the name of your lambda function, what to exclude in the package and the trigger http events.

```
functions:
  index:
    handler: dist/index.handler
    
    events:
    - http:
        cors: true
        path: '/'
        method: any
    - http:
        cors: true
        path: '{proxy+}'
        method: any
```

If we take a look at this yml file, you can see that we have 2 HTTP events, one for root path and one for proxy path.

**A question that I asked myself when reading through it, so what does this event part do?**

This part of the yml basically creates your endpoints in the [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) service of AWS (if you are using AWS as a provider).
API Gateway is a service made by AWS that lets you map requests into other services of AWS, such as a lambda function.

When you run the command `sls deploy`
after entering your credentials using `sls config credentials` the serverless framework will create OR modify if exists a new lambda function based on the config you set up, and set up API Gateway endpoints linked to that lambda.

After deploying you will receive a link that activates that lambda.
The example I use basically uses an express serverless solution that someone created, basically a proxy code that knows how to receive API Gateway request object and transform it to express and activate it without having a server running.

Note: Serverless is using CloudFormation to create a stack in order to upload and deploy the lambda function, I think with this way you can upload more than 250mb unzipped, because my project currently is 450mb unzipped, I am not sure about this but when I tried uploading a bigger zip, my lambda started overflowing, as in saying that it is missing some modules, I guess because of the size.

Or maybe serverless really optimizes the modules so the uploaded package is much smaller than what you expect. If someone knows about this, +1!

Answer (score 0):

You must provide more info about your architecture.
 Have you used `Blueprint` with `microservice`?
 Then choose  `microservice-http-endpoint`.

Take a look at [microservice-http-endpoint] example.
[1](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-app-examples/tree/master/javascript/microservice-http-endpoint)

Answer (score -1):

You can convert you whole express app in a lambda function and process request as they come in.

This blog shows how to do it for express: https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/

Similar thing can be tried for NestJS as well. So lambda function is basically a piece of code that gets executed as the request come in. There are limitation on the size of the code and time to execute a job which is platform specific.